# Module Not Found error even though I have installed pygame

Tags: python, pygame, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to import pygame in a venv. However, after I activate the venv and enter

```
pip install pygame
```

into the cmd prompt, I am told the

```
requirement is satisfied
```

yet when I run my code it says:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'pygame'
```

Can someone please tell me why this is not working, thank you.enter image description here

[image: Error message]
[image: Requirement satisfied to import pygame]

Comment: Are you importing pygame in the first line of the code you have provided? Otherwise you're doing "from" imports and never importing pygame itself

Comment: Have you tried typing: pip list to see if it appears ?

Comment: Try `python -m pip install pygame` rather than `pip install pygame`. To verify, you can check which interpreter `pip` is pointing to by comparing `python -m pip -V` and `pip -V`

Comment: @Guillermo J. No, I did put import pygame above that line

Comment: @Alfredo Mauri I typed that in, and it does include pygame in the list, but I still don't understand why the program just doesn't run

Comment: I think that the pip you are using is pointing to a different version of Python, most probably Python2. Do you have multiple versions installed?

Comment: @Kingsley Thank you, this is working now!